# In foreach last value alone displaying in the output , other values are not displaying in the output?

Tags: php, foreach, drupal-7

```
 $address_query = db_query('......');    
 $address1 ='';
 $address2 ='';
 $address3 ='';
 $address4 ='';
 $address5 ='';
 $state = '';
 $pincode ='';
 $addcategory ='';
 $residence ='';
 $adddaterpt ='';

 foreach($address_query as $adds) 
 {
$address1 .= $adds->addressline1;
$address2 .= $adds->addressline2;
$address3 .= $adds->addressline3;
$address4 .= $adds->addressline4;
$address5 .= $adds->addressline5;
$state .= $adds->state_name;
$pincode .= $adds->pincode;
$addcategory .= $adds->addcategory_name;
$residence .= $adds->residence_name;
$adddaterpt .= $adds->date_reported;
$addrptdate = substr($adddaterpt, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 2, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 4, 4);


   $report.='<tr>
   <table id="address1">
             <tr><b>ADDRESS:</b>' . $address1 . $address2 . $address3 . $address4 . $address5 . $state . $pincode . '</tr>
             <tr><td><b>CATEGORY:</b>' . $addcategory . '</td> 
                 <td><b>RESIDENCE CODE:</b>' . $residence . '</td>
                 <td><b>DATE REPORTED:</b>' . $addrptdate . '</td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         </tr>';
   }
   $report.='</table>';
```

While executing this code, I'm getting an last value of an foreach(). Other values are not displaying to me.

It contains 4 rows in $address_query , but last row values only displaying.

Please suggest me , i have done any mistake in my code.

Comment: Why are you concat'ing everything? Surely you only want the current part of  address, not that part of the address and of every previous address in one string?

Comment: use just echo not concate string.

Comment: I'm generating an report , so only concatenating everything. It looks like [addressline1] = S/O NATARAJAN NO 2 MARIAMMAN KOIL STREET
    [addressline2] = T
    [addressline3] = POIGAI VILLAGE VELLORE TK AND DISTPIN 63
    [addressline4] = 32114
    [addressline5] = VELLO-TN
    [state_name] = Tamil Nadu
    [pincode] = 632114
    [date_reported] =31102014
    [addcategory_name] =Permanent Address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello friend actually you cannot able to use table tag inside the tr tag and you are not declared the variable $report directly used in for-each statement.

Try this code

```
$address_query = db_query('......');    
$adddaterpt ='';
$report = '<table>';
foreach($address_query as $adds) 
{
    $adddaterpt .= $adds->date_reported;
    $addrptdate = substr($adddaterpt, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 2, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 4, 4);
    $report.='<tbody id="address1">
         <tr><td><b>ADDRESS:</b>' . $adds->addressline1 . $adds->addressline2 . $adds->addressline3 . $adds->addressline4 . $adds->addressline5 . $adds->state_name . $adds->pincode . '</td></tr>
         <tr><td><b>CATEGORY:</b>' . $adds->addcategory_name . '</td> 
             <td><b>RESIDENCE CODE:</b>' . $adds->residence_name . '</td>
             <td><b>DATE REPORTED:</b>' . $addrptdate . '</td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>';
}
$report.='</table>';
```

Comment: hello friend,  Still i'm getting an last value of the query. Other values are not displaying in the report.
 ( [quickappid] => 4 [addressline1] => S/O NATARAJAN NO 2 MARIAMMAN KOIL STREET [addressline2] => T [addressline3] => POIGAI VILLAGE VELLORE TK AND DISTPIN 63 [addressline4] => 32114 [addressline5] => VELLO-TN [state_name] => Tamil Nadu [pincode] => 632114 [date_reported] => 31102014 [addcategory_name] => Permanent Address )

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the question, but the issue may be with your concatenation.

In your current code, each loop continues to add to the following variables.

```
    $address1
    $address2
    $address3
    $address4
    $address5
    $state
    $pincode
    $addcategory 
    $residence
    $adddaterpt
```

So, by the end of your loop, each variable is stacked with information from each prior iteration.

You need reset your variables for each loop OR, as in the example below, remove your concatenation completely. So:

```
foreach($address_query as $adds) {
    $address1    = $adds->addressline1;
    $address2    = $adds->addressline2;
    $address3    = $adds->addressline3;
    $address4    = $adds->addressline4;
    $address5    = $adds->addressline5;
    $state       = $adds->state_name;
    $pincode     = $adds->pincode;
    $addcategory = $adds->addcategory_name;
    $residence   = $adds->residence_name;
    $adddaterpt  = $adds->date_reported;
    $addrptdate  = substr($adddaterpt, 0, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 2, 2) . "-" . substr($adddaterpt, 4, 4);
}
```

Hope this helps! If not, please be a little more clear with your question. :)

Comment: If i remove concatenation also it display only last value of an foreach statement.

Comment: Have you tried the above? I understand why you're concatenating the `$report` variable but concatenating everything else seems a little pointless, unless I am missing something.

Comment: $address_query contains for address values (ie) 4 rows. In database it shows all rows, but while fetching values using foreach it fetch the values and displays only the last row.  others row values are not displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can do it dirctly as well why u r storing the data in variable just directly use it you are in foreach loop already...    
foreach($address_query as $adds) 
 {
   $report.='<tr>
   <table id="address1">
          <tr><b>ADDRESS:</b>' . $adds->addressline1. $adds->addressline2 .    $adds->addressline3 . $adds->addressline4 . $adds->addressline5 . $adds->state_name . $adds->pincode . '</tr>
          </table>
     </tr>';
```

}

Comment: Now it display empty array like ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray.

Comment: checkout $address_query that it has values or not

Comment: its having an values.[addressline1] = S/O NATARAJAN NO 2 MARIAMMAN KOIL STREET
    [addressline2] = T
    [addressline3] = POIGAI VILLAGE VELLORE TK AND DISTPIN 63
    [addressline4] = 32114
    [addressline5] = VELLO-TN
    [state_name] = Tamil Nadu
    [pincode] =632114
    [date_reported] =31102014
    [addcategory_name] =Permanent Address

Comment: you can do it like this as well
$address1 .= $adds->addressline1. ',' ;

Comment: i think u want some thing like this
$address = $address1,$address2,$address3......... and so on

Comment: In database I'm having 4 rows with different address and it fetching and displaying only 4th row address. Its not displays other 3rows.

Comment: There is no problem in concentation.